# setcontent in tinymce does not copy styling of html

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I cant get tinymce to use the styling of the html sent to it by setContent. for eaxmple when i edit `<h3>Amit</h3>`, tinyMCE shows this in bold, even though the text is not in bold.

How do i make tinymce use the styling of the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please verify if `h3` is defined as valid element in your tinymce init!

Answer (score 1):

If you have specific CSS styling for your H3, make sure you are including the css file in the configuration of TinyMCE via the [content_css](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acontent_css) config item.